# Comparar numeros, retornar com o de maior valor

Tags: javascript

Ok, basicamente preciso criar uma função simples em javascript em que entre com dois valores, e ele retorna o maior deles. Minha solução foi:

```js
function eMaior(A,B) {
  
  if (A > B) {return: A}
  else {return B}
  
}
```

porém não funciona e não entendo o que estou fazendo de errado. alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kathryn, é só remover o *:* deste trecho {return: A}

Comment: omeudeus, um negócio tão pequeno hahahaha obrigada rodrigo!!! <3

Comment: Bem vindo à vida de programador :)

Comment: Procure sempre olhar o log de erros ;)